# Generate and then rasterize vector shape in Monogame/XNA

Tags: xna, monogame, procedural-generation

I apologize if this is too broad, but I can't seem to find information on this anywhere (perhaps I am searching for the wrong thing?)

Anyways, I'm making a simple game where the player visits different, small, circular planets.  I've successfully made a simple circle texture directly with a `for` loop, but I've run into a few problems:

- How can I easily add variation to the landscape (e.g. Perlin noise)
- How can I detect where the surface of the planet is?
- How can I easily add objects to the surface of the planet?

I realized that all 3 of these problems could most likely be solved if the planet was generated with a vector polygon.  Noise could be easily applied, and the normal of each edge could help with surface detection/object placement.

However, I could barely find any info on the subject.  Let me be clear - I don't want to *directly* render a vector shape; I want to invisibly create a semi-random polygon, and then create a filled-in texture based on that convex shape.

Is there any easy way to do this?  Is there a better way to execute this idea in general?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to render the polygon to a Texture2D and then use it as a texture the rest of tge game?

Comment: Yes, that's actually preferred.